# Getting a secret from azure keyvault with node from a linux vm with MSI

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm having issues getting a secret from azure keyvault using the azure-keyvault package from a node application running on a linux vm on azure.

I am using the following code:

```
import * as KeyVault from 'azure-keyvault';
import * as msRestAzure from 'ms-rest-azure'

function getKeyVaultCredentials(){
    return msRestAzure.loginWithVmMSI();
}

function getKeyVaultSecret(credentials) {
    let keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials,null);
    return keyVaultClient.getSecret("my keyvault url here", 'my keyvault secret name here', "", null,null);
}

getKeyVaultCredentials().then(
    getKeyVaultSecret
).then(function (secret){
    //not getting here....
}).catch(function (err) {
    //...error handling...
});
```

I am getting a 401 response when calling getSecret.
There are permissions set to the machine on the keyvault and MSI.
In the error I get there doesn't seem to be any header of authentication or a token, although I do see a header which looks like an authentication header on the response.

Is there anything I am missing in my implementation?

**EDIT:**
It looks like the example I've shared here would have worked if I would use

```
msRestAzure.loginWithVmMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net' });
```

instead of calling it with no params.

Comment: I'm confused. Where are you requesting a token? You should be able to see your token in the response header from your https request. Also you need to be using callbacks.

Comment: @Rthomas529 I'm trying to use the azure-keyvault package... so some of the information is hidden from me. are you suggesting to just use the regular API with simple http requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your keyvault, make sure you have added the service principal(created automatically by enabling the MSI) in the `Access policies` with correct secret permission. Then try to click `Click to show advanced access policies`-> choose the `Enable access to Azure Virtual Machines for deployment` option-> Save.

Here is a code sample, you could check the part of retrieving a secret value.

```
var http = require('http');
const KeyVault = require('azure-keyvault');
const msRestAzure = require('ms-rest-azure');


var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
});

// The ms-rest-azure library allows us to login with MSI by providing the resource name. In this case the resource is Key Vault.
// For public regions the resource name is Key Vault
msRestAzure.loginWithAppServiceMSI({resource: 'https://vault.azure.net'}).then( (credentials) => {
    const keyVaultClient = new KeyVault.KeyVaultClient(credentials);

    var vaultUri = "https://" + "<YourVaultName>" + ".vault.azure.net/";

    // We're setting the Secret value here and retrieving the secret value
    keyVaultClient.setSecret(vaultUri, 'my-secret', 'test-secret-value', {})
        .then( (kvSecretBundle, httpReq, httpResponse) => {
            console.log("Secret id: '" + kvSecretBundle.id + "'.");
            return keyVaultClient.getSecret(kvSecretBundle.id, {});
        })
        .then( (bundle) => {
            console.log("Successfully retrieved 'test-secret'");
            console.log(bundle);
        })
        .catch( (err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    // Below code demonstrates how to retrieve a secret value

    // keyVaultClient.getSecret(vaultUri, "AppSecret", "").then(function(response){
    //     console.log(response);    
    // })
});
```

For more details, you could refer to : [**Set and retrieve a secret from Azure Key Vault using a Node Web App**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/key-vault-node-getting-started).

Comment: I noticed you are using loginWithAppServiceMSI in your example, but I don't have an AppService, I have a regular VM, shouldn't I be using loginWithVmMSI ?

Comment: @Mithir Yes, I think you should use loginWithVmMSI in your case. BTW, have you checked your permissions first?

Comment: I have just implemented getting the secret with plain http requests and it worked. I am first getting a token and then getting the secret with an authorization header which has the token details inside - so the permissions are OK. I still prefer using the package but I am not sure what is missing...

Comment: @Mithir Could you follow the sample to have a try? No matter use the msi of app service or vm, the logic should be similar.

Comment: Ok thank you very much... it seems like I've missed the resource part in my example... Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

This has now been simplified in the new `@azure/keyvault-secrets` package where the `SecretClient` can take the `DefaultAzureCredential` from the `@azure/identity` package which in turn is smart enough to use the MSI details when run in your VM as well as the developer credentials like VS Code or Azure CLI when in your local dev environment. You can learn more about this in the [readme for @azure/identity](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/identity)

With this, your code would be simplified to

```js
const { SecretClient } = require("@azure/keyvault-secrets");
const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");

async function getValue(secretName, secretVersion) {
  const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
  const client = new SecretClient(KEY_VAULT_URI, credential);
  const secret = await client.getSecret(secretName);
  return secret.value;
}
```

To move your application from the older `azure-keyvault` package which is now deprecated, you can see the [migration guide to the new @azure/keyvault-secrets](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/keyvault/keyvault-secrets/migration-guide.md)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [read-azure-secrets](https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-azure-secrets) which will retrieve all secrets from the azure key vault.

For example

```
let secretClient = require('read-azure-secrets');

async function loadKeyVaultValues() {

    let applicationID = '';
    let applicationSecret = '';
    let vaultURL = 'https://<your-key-vault-name>.vault.azure.net/';
    let secrets = await secretClient.getSecrets(applicationID, applicationSecret, vaultURL);

    secrets.forEach(secret => {
        console.log(secret);
    });

}

loadKeyVaultValues();
```